# Move запущенного файла

Tags: c#

Дано:
1.Запущенная программа на C#.
Как сделать так, чтобы при её запуске, она переместила себя в папку C:\Users\ams\AppData\Local\Temp и при этом удалилась из запущенного места(Где она находится на данный момент).
Естественно это должно быть сделано посредством кода на с# в этой программе.

Comment: скопировать свой исполняемый файл в нужное место, запуститься оттуда, и удалить старый файл - так делать правильно. Неправильно - просто использовать Move и надеятся что никто(и ни что) не успело занять файл на чтение.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. В Windows запущеный/открытый файл нельзя ни переместить, ни даже переименовать (что, по сути, то же самое).

Comment: К примеру, как же тогда всякие вирусы переносят себя куда-нибудь в temp и удаляются из места, куда были сохранены?

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Запущенное приложение без труда может переименовать свой .exe файл при помощи простого `.Move()`, правда не всегда и есть некие ограничения.

Comment: Ответ не имеет с реальностью ничего общего, запущенный файл не налогает ограничений на перемещение\переименование\чтение. Только на запись есть запрет(запись\удаление)

Comment: @Граф, делают копию файла, запуск из нового места(с параметром) и после - удаление старого, так делают нормальные "вирусы" =) прямое перемещение не желательно делать(могут быть проблемы в работе, если всё не предусмотреть)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, и как же так сделать на коде c#?

Comment: Что именно? просто применить move к Файлу? очень подозреваю что в справке написано(переписывать сюда msdn смысла не вижу). Как правильно - общий смысл описан, за вас делать работу - не вижу смысла, направление поиска вполне понятно из комментария под вопросом.
Если вы готовы оплатить час моей работы - могу написать и на шарпе за вас функцию(рабочий пример) который будет переносить себя в любую указанную папку =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Да, действительно. Странно, что с открытым файлом ничего нельзя сделать, а с запущенным можно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ничего странного, запуск = отображение в память(MemoryMap), а не открытие на чтение\запись, я вам больше скажу в винде(про никсы не в курсе) - можно открыть файл на ЗАПИСЬ и разрешить остальным открывать его на ЗАПИСЬ =) (простите за капс, хотелось выделить именно это слово), скорее всего вы в курсе, но на всякий - флаги(дополнительные) открытия файла https://yadi.sk/i/9p4Oia7mmotMGA

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, метод Move не будет работать, что уже проверенно.
Даже перегруженный с аргументом true.
Заходить на оверфлоу и просить деньги за ответы.

Comment: Я за ответы денег не прошу =) про деньги я вам написал - "если вы хотите чтобы я **за вас написал это** на вашем ЯП(шарп) - будьте добры оплатить это как работу", если хотите бесплатно - попробуйте сделать как описано в совете под ВОПРОСОМ, и когда что то не получится задайте уточняющий вопрос. Ответы - бесплатно, Код за вас и для вас(вас - тех кто не желает понять\разобраться сам) - платно. В вашем вопросе я не увидел ни желания ни попыток разобраться, отсюда и тон общения, вы даже не удосужились привести текст ошибки или код которым вы пробовали решить задачу. За сим откланяюсь =)